# Hide "Show More" button from Today widget in iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, widget, today-extension

I am building an iOS Today widget, and while testing for iOS 10, I see a "Show More" / "Show Less" button on the top right of the widget header. How can I remove this button? I am using Objective-C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In iOS 10, as far as I know, the show more option is new and we cannot remove it, but we can modify it as needed.

The following code will allow you to automatically size the Today widget. Just change the table or collection view or whatever you used in your project.

```
static CGFloat padding = 25.0;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // This will remove extra separators from tableview
    self.articleTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    // Add the iOS 10 Show More ability
    [self.extensionContext setWidgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode:NCWidgetDisplayModeExpanded];
}

- (void)widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize {
   if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact){
       // Changed to compact mode
       self.preferredContentSize = maxSize;
   }
   else{
       // Changed to expanded mode
       self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.articleTableView.contentSize.width, self.articleTableView.contentSize.height + padding);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have used this as reference  --> https://github.com/sighmon/NI-ipad/blob/master/New%20Internationalist%20Magazine%20Australia%20Extension/TodayViewController.m

Comment: It is possible to remove the 'Show More' button... see below.

Answer (score 10):

In `viewDidLoad` you can set the largest available display mode.

```
[self.extensionContext setWidgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode:NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact];
```

This will remove the Show More/Less button, but it may not be what you want. The maximum allowed size for the compact view is fairly small.

You can implement:

`-(void)widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize`

to update your `preferredContentSize`. The `maxSize` parameter will be the maximum allowed size for the `activeDisplayMode`.

Comment: Thanks Jervine - This is working for me, but my actual need is that - i don't want Show more/less button in Expanded mode. Is there any way to hide the button in the expanded mode.

Comment: The quick test I ran had it hide the button when setting the AvailableDisplayMode to `NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact`

Comment: Any luck? It must be possible since I have apps on my iphone with expanded mode by default without show less/more button

Answer (score 2):

```
-[NCWidgetProviding widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:withMaximumSize:]
```

Is probably what you're looking for, I would reference [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/iOS10APIDiffs/Objective-C/NotificationCenter.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly you cannot hide it and should conform to the

```
widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:withMaximumSize:
```

widgets that doesn't show this control were not build for iOS10

Answer (score 1):

I know the original post mentions using objective-c
but in the event anyone needs the swift answer, here it is

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .compact
}
```

When set to compact, the app will only support compact mode i.e. show less/show show buttons/functionality will be gone.

here's some [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsextensioncontext/1649133-widgetlargestavailabledisplaymod) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Placing this line of code inside the widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange delegate method solved my problem.

```
[self.extensionContext setWidgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode:NCWidgetDisplayModeExpanded];
```

If you wanna hide the show more/ show less option replace NCWidgetDisplayModeExpanded with NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact.

```
- (void)widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode
                         withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize {

    [self.extensionContext setWidgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode:NCWidgetDisplayModeExpanded];

}
```